# How to file 'Invalid requests[0].updateTextStyle: At least one field must be listed in 'fields'. (Use '*' to indicate all fields.)">'

Tags: python, google-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm trying to update a google docs and when I try and push the update it says `googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/1UeorM9adOh8Nds1Z457RRKBZMkh0VZ_kn_jllpkzh7U:batchUpdate?alt=json returned "Invalid requests[0].updateTextStyle: At least one field must be listed in 'fields'. (Use '*' to indicate all fields.)">` and I have no clue what is means.

This is the method that throws the error

```py
def update(request):
    result = service.documents().batchUpdate(
        documentId=DOCUMENT_ID, body={'requests': [request]}).execute()
    return result
```

If anyone can help that would be great!

This is what my request is

```py
request = {
  'updateTextStyle': {
    'range': {
      'segmentId': None,
      'startIndex': None, # gets filled with the proper number
      'endIndex': None # gets filled with the proper number
    },
    'textStyle': {
      "bold": False,
      "italic": False,
      "underline": False,
      "strikethrough": False,
      "smallCaps": False,
      "backgroundColor": {
        'color': {
          'rgbColor': {
            'red': 0.2,
            'green': 0.2,
            'blue': 0.2
          }
        }
      },
      "foregroundColor": {
        'color': {
          'rgbColor': {
            'red': 0.96,
            'green': 0.96,
            'blue': 0.96
          }
        }
        },
    "fontSize": {
        'magnitude': 10,
        'unit': 'PT'
    },
  "weightedFontFamily": {
    'fontFamily': 'Courier New OS',
    'weight': 400
  },
  "baselineOffset": 'NONE',
  "link": None
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that providing ``request``, which can replicate your issue, is will help users think of your solution. If you can do, please add it to your question.

Comment: ok, I'm adding that

Comment: Thank you for replying. I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`At least one field must be listed in 'fields'. (Use '*' to indicate all fields.)` means that the property of `fields` is not set in your request body. So for example, how about this modification?

#### From:

```
  },
  "baselineOffset": 'NONE',
  "link": None
    }
  }
}
```

#### To:

```
            },
            "baselineOffset": 'NONE',
            "link": None
        },
        "fields": "*"  # Added
    }
}
```

#### Note:

- This answer supposes that you have already been able to update the Google Document using Google Docs API.
- **This modification supposes that when you use this request body, `None` of `'range': {'segmentId': None, 'startIndex': None, 'endIndex': None},` and `"link": None` are replaced to the correct values.**

#### Reference:

- [UpdateTextStyleRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#updatetextstylerequest)

Comment: Well, it did change something, but it doesn't look like the correct thing to do, this is what is says now `googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/1UeorM9adOh8Nds1Z457RRKBZMkh0VZ_kn_jllpkzh7U:batchUpdate?alt=json returned "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "fields" at 'requests[0]': Cannot find field.">`

Comment: Wait no, I put the fields in the wrong stop, you were right, thanks!

Comment: @Max Gordon Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.